# Access the title when defining page headers?

Tags: header-footer, titles, koma-script

I'm trying to wrap up some stuff into a document class that I have always coded manually into the document files so far. During this, I ran into a problem. Given the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Of Foo And Bar}
\author{Me And Myself} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Of Foo And Bar\\\headmark}
\automark{section}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents  
\clearpage
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsection{Baz} 
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{Boo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar} 
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsection{Baz} 
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

I need to remove the redundant title in the call to `\ihead` and replace it with something that inserts the title I specified earlier using `\title{...}`. How do I access the title that was set with `\title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the title via the command `\mytitle` if you add

```
\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\makeatother
```

in your preamble **after** `\title`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Of Foo And Bar}
\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\makeatother

\author{Me And Myself} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\mytitle\\\headmark}
\automark{section}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents  
\clearpage
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, the title is accessible via `\thetitle` if the `titling` package is loaded, but the latter interferes with the formatting of KOMA-script classes.

Comment: Works perfectly - since I'm about to move the stuff into a document class, I embedded the `\let` command into an `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: I could have sworn I did that last night - must have been too late...

Answer (score 3):

If you "dare" to "hack" into the system, read Jubobs answer. If you don't, you can define your own command to substitute the `\title` command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\titledefined}{}
\newcommand{\definetitle}[1]{%
\title{#1}
\renewcommand{\titledefined}{#1}
}

\definetitle{Of Foo And Bar}
\author{Me And Myself} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\titledefined\\\headmark}
\automark{section}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents  
\clearpage
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsection{Baz} 
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{Boo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Bar} 
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsection{Baz} 
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

It's longer than Jubobs answer, but it's more suitable to your personal package(s) [if you have them]. You can put the command `\definetitle` in your personal package (which you load by default), and then simply use it instead of `\title`.